# How to maintain unique values using EF Core CosmosDB provider

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, azure-cosmosdb, ef-core-2.0

My class look like:

```
public class PortalAccount
{
        public Guid id{ get; set; }
        public string PortalAccountName { get; set; }
        public int PortalAccountState { get; set; }
        public string Address { get; set; }
}


protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
  modelBuilder.Entity<PortalAccount>().HasIndex(x => new { x.Address, x.PortalAccountState 
   }).IsUnique();
modelBuilder.Entity<PortalAccount>().ToContainer("PortalAccount").HasNoDiscriminator().HasPartitionKey("PortalAccountName");
}
```

While i'm trying to create a record with PortalAccountState = 1 and Address = "Addr1" twice it is inserting in Cosmos Database..It's not restricting me..

Note: I tried with     `modelBuilder.Entity<PortalAccount>().HasAlternateKey(x => new { x.Address, x.PortalAccountState });`.
By using above code, it restricts me not to create duplicate records but while i'm trying to update the record its throwing exception.

I need to work the code for both create and update.
Could someone help me with this issue??